# DataFrame has float values but calling to_csv() on it generates an empty CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

Consider my following code:

```
columns = ['tf-idf','bag_of_words']
index = ['MultinomialNB', 'LinearSVC', 'LogisticRegression', \
        'DecisionTreeClassifier','MLPClassifier']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns, index = index)

estimators_dict = OrderedDict([('MultiNomialNB', MultinomialNB()), \
                    ('LinearSVC', LinearSVC()), \
                    ('LogisticRegression', LogisticRegression()), \
                    ('DecisionTreeClassifier', DecisionTreeClassifier()), \
                    ('MLPClassifier',MLPClassifier(max_iter=10))])

transformers_dict = OrderedDict([('tf-idf', TfidfVectorizer(max_features=500)), \
                                    ('bag_of_words', CountVectorizer())]) 
steps = []

for transformer_name, transformer in transformers_dict.items():         
    steps.append((transformer_name, transformer))

    for estimator_name, estimator in estimators_dict.items():           
        steps.append((estimator_name, estimator))
        model = Pipeline(steps)
        predicted_labels = cross_val_predict(model, all_features,all_labels, cv=5)

        # f1 is float       
        f1 = f1_score(all_labels, predicted_labels, average = 'weighted')
        # writing to DataFrame
        df[transformer_name][estimator_name] = round(f1,2)          
        # This correctly shows the value which just written
        print(str(df[str(transformer_name)][str(estimator_name)]))  # line a 

        del steps[1]    

    del steps[0]        

# but writing to csv create a file with no values whatsoever
df.to_csv('classification_results_f1score') # line b
```

Quick little context: In my classification task I am using a set of feature transformers and another set of sklearn classifiers. I am running all possible combinations of these two sets to see which model performs the best.

I am calculating f1-score (a float value) of each model and storing it in a dataframe. The value is successfully written to the dataframe. I am able to verify the same by accessing it. (*line a*)

But after all the model runs are over (end of both the for loops) when I write the dataframe to a csv it is generating a csv as follows:

```
,tf-idf,bag_of_words
MultinomialNB,,
LinearSVC,,
LogisticRegression,,
DecisionTreeClassifier,,
MLPClassifier,,
```

What seems to be the issue here? Why are the values not showing up in the csv?

Comment: What happens if you specify `float_format` in `to_csv()`?

Comment: @Khris still the same.

Comment: on a sidenote, why not just do `steps = [(transformer_name, transformer), (estimator_name, estimator)]` in the inner for-loop, and use `df.loc[estimator_name, transformer_name]` instead of `df[][]`. Especially this `df[][]` can cause some strange problems with view and copies. Also `print(str(df[str(transformer_name)][str(estimator_name)]))` contains a lot of unnecessary `str()` calls

Comment: what does `print(df)` say at the end, to see whether the `df` is empty, or the `to_csv` is wonky

Comment: @PaleBlueDot I stumbled upon this in the review queue. Personally, I don't find the question off-topic and voted to leave it open. Nevertheless, I would advise you to restrain yourself from comments in a certain tone, which might be interpreted negatively. As for the question itself, have you tried mocking the data frame and building a CSV from there? Or maybe saving the f1 measurements as floats and configuring the decimal precision in `to_csv`?